# How start Flutter (Error creating project)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, ubuntu-18.04

When I want to create a project it knocks out the following:

```
Error creating project
Flutter create command was unsuccessful
```

Some details(Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS , JDK 11 , Android Studio 4.1.1)

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: It seems Android Studio is not installed yet. If it is installed currently, you can try to restart your machine.

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Linux, locale uk_UA.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    ✗ Cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/open-jdk/bin/java to determine the version
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
 Similarly in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Windows user, but it's maybe a problem of the `Path` of Java at `PATH environment`

1- open `PATH environment`.

2- remove everything Java related that does not point to the JDK folder.

3- add just field called  `JAVA_HOME` and give it the value of The Java SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter seems to be installed.
You should run `flutter create app_name`, where `app_name` is a folder to be created (does not exist).
The name of the folder should be in lowercase and no spaces